# How do I indent the first line of a paragraph using HTML inline styling?

Tags: html, email, html-email, inline, styling

I'm creating an **HTML email** and I do not want to use CSS styling in the head (for cross platform compatibility reasons). I need to set an indention for the first line of the paragraph using **inline styling** *only*.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
<p style="text-indent: 50px">
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try using [**`&nbsp;`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in sequence, and experiment to find the number you need.

```
<p> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; This is a paragraph. </p>
```

looks like this:

This is a paragraph.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: From what I understand some email clients won't recognize this method.

Comment: This does not resemble *"styling"*. It's an attempt at replicating styling by changing content. CSS was introduced to keep style and content separate. For good reason. It's unclear, how this received any upvotes at all.